# Finding semi-major axis and specific mechanical energy, etc

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I don't know how to do this. I need a really good explanation that shows how to get the answer.

Question: An Earth satellite’s orbit is at a 45 degree inclination. It has a perigee altitude of 400 kilometers and an apogee altitude of 2000 kilometers. It has a specific angular momentum of $54,653.38 \, \rm{km^2/s}$. What are its semi-major axis and its specific mechanical energy, its period and velocities at
apogee and perigee?

Use this information to answer the question.

Equations:
$$a = (r_a + r_p)/2$$
$$r_a = a (1 + e)$$
$$r_p = a (1 - e)$$
$$p = b^2/a = a (1 – e^2)$$
$$h = r_p v_p = r_a v_a$$
$$\varepsilon = - \mu/(2a)$$
$$P = 2\pi\sqrt{a^3/\mu}$$

Use:
Earth radius = $6378.1363 \, \rm{km}$
Gravitational parameter $\mu = 3.986012 × 10^5 \, \rm{km^3/s^2}$

Comment: What difficulty are you having determining the semimajor axis from the apogee and perigee altitudes? Do you know what semimajor axis means? Do you know what apogee and perigee mean? Do you know what altitude means?

Comment: @Ghoster Presumably, it's specific angular momentum.

Comment: Your question will be closed unless you explain what you do and don’t understand. Saying “i don’t know how to do this” is not useful information. We don’t solve homework problems; we help you understand specific things that you are confused about.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: @Ghoster Fair point. It's not clear where the OP is having problems doing these calculations, especially considering they've been given all the relevant equations. (Assuming the equations were originally in a less mangled state than what we see here).

Comment: the thing that is confusing me here is how to find the semi major axis, i know that i can use this formula to find the semi major axis a = {(ra + rp)/2 but in the question it gives  "perigee altitude and apogee altitude" and it is not the same with radius perigee and radius apogee.

Comment: @Have The radial distance is just the Earth radius + altitude.